# Excel error with intersect code

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon! I'm having another issue, and can't seem to figure it out. In this way too long filter macro, I have code that looks for the active cell within a range, and if it's there, performs a filter:

```
       ElseIf Not (Intersect(ActiveCell, OpenFindingsRange)) Then
    SourceFindings.Select
        'Unfilter data
        Application.Goto (Sheets("Source-Findings").Range("A1"))
        If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblFindings").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=FilterOperatingGroup
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblFindings").Range.AutoFilter Field:=36, Criteria1:=OpenStatus
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblFindings").Range.AutoFilter Field:=37, Criteria1:="Yes"
```

If the active cell isn't in that range, it should go to the next Else If statement, but that's not happening. I'm getting the following error: Object variable or With block variable not set.

I can't get around this, and for whatever reason, I can't get error handling to bypass it.

Thoughts?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intersect()**, as you are using it, will return a *Range* and not a *Boolean.*

Comment: Much appreciated! I've added "Set isect1 = Application.Intersect(ActCell, OpenFindingsRange)" and then "ElseIf Not isect1 Is Nothing Then" and that fixed the issue. Thanks!!!